# How do I just get an email address after authenticating with oAuth2? - google-api-nodejs-client

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to just get an email address after authenticating with oAuth2.  After I get a `code` when I validate with a google account, I go and get the user from Google Plus, like this:

```
let oAuth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_CLIENT_CALLBACK);
const tokens = await getToken(oAuth2Client, code);
oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
plus('v1').people.get({ userId: 'me', auth: oAuth2Client }, function(err, response) {
  .... This repsonse is the full user object from Google Plus
});
```

How do I just get the email address, or a list of email addresses?  I don't want all the other Google Plus info.  I have already set my scope to `email`, but I still get lots of other information.  I am assuming that I need to make a request to something other than `plus`, but I can't find what to do in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set email scope (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`), you can use [`oauth2("v2").userinfo.v2.me.get`](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/37347b5df754f4f6922b928f943301d6a62f81cc/apis/oauth2/v2.ts#L111-L186) :

```
var google = require('googleapis');

....

google.oauth2("v2").userinfo.v2.me.get({
    auth: oAuth2Client
}, function(e, profile) {
    if ("email" in profile) {
        console.log(profile.email);
    } else {
        console.log("scope email not set");
    }
});
```